# Writing out a CSV to Response.OutputStream also writes out the HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, httpresponse, export-to-csv

I am attempting to write an ASP.NET page that allows a user to download their data from a database in a CSV format. I have written the below code which is in the code behind and will run on a button click. Here is what I have written:

```
  private void RunBackup()
  {
    Button1.Enabled = false;

    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=backup.csv");

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var queryString = "SELECT * FROM [Data] WHERE [ID] = @id";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = userId;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            // Write header row.
            for (int columnCounter = 0; columnCounter < reader.FieldCount; columnCounter++)
            {
                if(columnCounter > 0)
                {
                    writer.Write(separator);
                }
                writer.Write(reader.GetName(columnCounter));
            }
            writer.WriteLine(string.Empty);

            // Write out the data.
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Write out the column.
                for (int columnCounter = 0; columnCounter < reader.FieldCount; columnCounter++) 
                {
                    if (columnCounter > 0) 
                    {
                        writer.Write(separator);
                    }
                    writer.Write(reader.GetValue(columnCounter).ToString().Replace(",", ";").Replace("\"", " "));
                }
                writer.WriteLine(string.Empty);
            }

            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        Button1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

It works great, except for the fact that not only do I get the CSV file with the SQL data, but I also get - at the very end of the file - the HTML of the page. I cannot figure out what is doing that, though I suspect it is something to do with the `Response` headers OR with the output to the `Response.OutputStream`.

I would appreciate any pointing in the right direction.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? I almost writing a report to csv,excel and any for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default ASP.Net renders the form as Html and put it into the response unless you tell the opposite, so that the form returns to the client. That's why you see an Html page into the downloaded file.

Add this code at the end of your `RunBackup()` method.

```
Response.End();
```

This will prevent more stuff to be added to your file.

Your code already has CompleteRequest() which is an important part to gracefully skip other events in the pipeline and prepare to end request. If the application is configured to buffer the output, Response.Flush(); can be added.